# Too many attr_accessible arguments creates performance hit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with 140 attr_accessible arguments in a Rails 3.2 model. Is there any kind of performance hit with this? I actually need all these attributes btw.

Comment: I am pretty sure you will not hit a performance issue with "only" 140 values used to extract values from a attributes hash. But since Ruby on Rails 3.2 reached its end of life-cycle with the release of Rails 5.0 on June 30th, 2016 and `attr_accessible` are replaced with `strong_params` in Rails 4 you make it harder and hard to migrate to newer Rails version with every new attribute you add protected that way.

Comment: @spickermann I will be upgrading to Rails 5 in the coming year. Why will all these attributes make it hard to migrate?

Comment: As I said `attr_accessible` was replaced with `strong_params`. The more complex your `attr_accessible` declarations are the more you have to change, test and refactor when you migrate to `strong_params`. Most of the time it is just copy and paste, but more attributes makes that process more error-prone and time consuming...